# Can't cast vector of struct to char*

Tags: c++

```
struct test{
    int x;
    float y;
    float array[100];
    test(){
        x = 0;
        y = 1.0;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
};

    std::vector<test> testArray;
    testArray.push_back(test());

    reinterpret_cast<char*>(testArray.front()), 2 * sizeof(test);
```

I want to cast testArray, to a char* so I can write to a file. Why isn't this example working? I am getting the following error:

```
file.cpp:71: error: invalid cast from type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<test> >::value_type {aka test}' to type 'char*'
     reinterpret_cast<char*>(testArray.front()), 2 * sizeof(test);
                                              ^
```

EDIT:

**Now I have a working example of how to read and write a complex struct vector to file.**

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
struct MyStruct{
    int x;
    float y;
    float array[100];
    MyStruct(){
        x = 0;
        y = 1.0;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            array[i] = i;
        }
    }
    void print(){
        std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
void write_pod(std::ofstream& out, T& t)
{
  out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
void read_pod(std::ifstream& in, T& t)
{
  in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t), sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
void write_pod_vector(std::ofstream& out, std::vector<T>& vect)
{
  long size = vect.size();
  write_pod<long>(out, size);
  out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vect.front()), size * sizeof(T));
}

template<typename T>
void read_pod_vector(std::ifstream& in, std::vector<T>& vect)
{
  long size;
  read_pod(in, size);
  vect.resize(size);
  in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vect.front()), size * sizeof(T));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "weighing_area");


    std::vector<MyStruct> testArray;
    testArray.push_back(MyStruct());
    testArray.push_back(MyStruct());


    ofstream myfile("/home/me/TEST.dat");
    write_pod_vector<MyStruct>(myfile, testArray);
    myfile.close();

    std::vector<MyStruct> readArray;
    ifstream readfile("/home/me/TEST.dat");
    read_pod_vector(readfile, readArray);

    cout << readArray.size() << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<readArray.size(); i++){
        MyStruct& myStruct = readArray[i];
        myStruct.print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: c++ is just being smart here. It makes no sense to cast it to a `char* ` and it would not work like you imagine if you write the result to a file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do; You might want `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&testArray.front())`.

Comment: Isn't there a syntax error in your `reinterpret_cast`? I.e. you close the call too early at `.front())`

Comment: @pingul I don't see a syntax error; it is  a cast expression followed by the comma operator.  (Makes no sense but I can't imagine what OP was trying to do with the stuff after the comma)

Comment: even something like this gives the same error:

    test mystruct;
    reinterpret_cast<char*>(mystruct);

Comment: @raaj you should maybe implement some functions to write the structs to a file/read them. If you just want to write the vector into a file this won't work

Comment: @raaj reinterpret_cast is for casting addresses,

Comment: i implemented them referencing some code i found online. here is it. it even works with PointCloudLibrary objects

Comment: @raaj are you sure it works? like reading the values in another program and check if they are the same? I am sure they "accidentally" work here because you read and write in the same run. You vectors will probably be invalid if you read the files after the program has exited

Comment: i just tested it. This code compiles you can try it

Comment: @raaj compile does not mean it works... try writing a file in one executable. then read it in another one and see if the values are the same. They should not be.

Comment: They are. I just ran it. You try it

Comment: why am i getting downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`front()` returns a `const` reference to the first element of the `vector`, so its type is `struct test`. Absent a custom type conversion operator, a `struct` cannot be cast to a pointer.

You can either take a `const` pointer of the `front()` or `data()`, or take an address of dereferenced `begin()` instead:

```
auto x = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(*testArray.begin()));
cout << (void*)x << endl;
```

Dereferencing `begin()` lets you avoid casting off the `const`-ness.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/g0kTry)